# Xcode gets stuck on copying a file when trying to build to run on device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I need to play an mp3 file in my application, and I have added it to my Project Navigator in the "Supporting Files" folder. When I build the application on the simulator, it runs fine.

When I attempt to build on my device, I get stuck in this stage:

[image]

This goes on for about 3 minutes and then I get two "An unknown error has occurred" windows that pop up.

I have tried resetting my MBP, iPhone, and Xcode. I have also tried cleaning my build folder. I thought this would be a simple/common problem, but my research has come up without a solution.

I found [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2777883?start=0&tstart=0), which advises to turn of "Parallelize Build," but that did not work either.

Has anyone experienced this problem and found a solution?

EDIT: Whenever I add any new media files (music/pictures) I get stuck on copying them.

Comment: does your device have enough space?

Comment: It should. I have 6.3GB available and the mp3 file is only 197kb.

Comment: Try deleting the mp3 and removing it from the project folder as well then copy it again making sure you are copying to target as well. That might solve the issue.

Comment: May your mp3 file has a problem ( like to broken already, but the media-player still can play it. ), to try others mp3 are fine ?

Comment: What is your optimization level set to under build settings?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, CodeMonkey and KuoMingLin, but those didn't seem to work. PWiggin - My optimization level is apparently "<multiple values>".

Comment: Does it work if you change your optimization to "None [-O0]"?

Comment: @PWiggin That didn't seem to work. Actually, whenever I add new media files to the project, I get stuck on copying them.

Answer (score 1):

In the info.plist you can add the key: **Application supports iTunes file sharing** and set it to **YES**. Then you be able to manage your app data using the iTunes. Open iTunes, go to your device and open the application tab.

Down in this page go to file sharing section and there you have your app Documents folder to pass all you data.

I hope this result useful.